# Best practice for rendering data into html with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I am trying to load some details of an item on-click of that item in some already defined div. I have 2 ways to do that.

Note: I am using python/django as backend, and jquery in frontend

I. My First way

**Views.py**

```
def get_item_data(id):
    obj = MyClass.objects.get(pk=id)
    html = """
              <div>All Details Here, 1. {0}, 2. {1}</div>
           """.format(str(obj.id), str(obj.name))

    return HttpResponse(html)
```

**myapp.js**

```
$('#myid').on('click', function(){
     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: GET_DATA,
        data: dataString,
        success: function(res) {
                $('#addl_container').html(res);
        }
    });
});
```

II. The Other way

**Views.py**

```
def get_item_data(id):
    obj = MyClass.objects.filter(pk=id).values()
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(obj))
```

**myapp.js**

```
$('#myid').on('click', function(){
     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: GET_DATA,
        data: dataString,
        success: function(res) {
                $('#addl_container').html(
                   "<div>All Details Here, 1. "+ res.id +", 2. "+ res.name + "</div>"
                );
        }
    });
});
```

Both of the process works.
I thought creating the html beforehand and loading it might not be a good choice as we are using python code to create the html and then loading it. Also it will nor work if i will try to access the same url from a different application.
Creating the html from jquery by extracting data from json response seems like a good solution but sometimes when the data is huge it needs more ram at the user's end, which makes the system slow.

I am confused which one to use, please suggest a better solution out of these two. Also suggest other solution better than this if any?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my opinion it depends on how much HTML you are rendering and how often. So for example, if you just need to render a small `<span>` then the way you are doing it is fine. But if you needed to render some large HTML, then it would be better using a template engine like [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)

Comment: Javascript = client processing.  Php = Server pocessing.   If you have a decent server, the second will be better for the user.  Many users still have relatively old PCs or, for work, what could be considered underpowered PCs especially when compared with a developer's PC.   Running too much on the client can kill performance / UX.

Comment: One other way if you have a larger html, then you can define template in `get_item_data` and return that template

Comment: Nice question man, you have a great future :D

Comment: I prefer using django's `render_to_string` method. So my view actually renders my template and returns that via an HttpResponse to my ajax request. Then simply insert it into the current template with javascript. I prefer this method because it takes raw html out of strings, and keeps it in an html template, rather in strings in your view or your javascript. PLUS, it also allows you to use django's template tags just like a normal django template, and you can pass a context to this template.

Comment: @CurtisOlson your ans is same as my first method of doing.  I also use render_to_string and that works.  But my question is which is best out of the above two methods

Comment: @binayr sort of, but it is slightly different - I've posted an answer to further explain. The main difference is de-coupling the template from the view

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to separate the template, business, and js logic as much as possible. It keeps it more pythonic and more within django design principles. This is indeed quite similar to your first method, but uses an html template, rather than printing html to a string in your view.

views.py

```
def get_item_data(id):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    obj = MyClass.objects.get(pk=id)
    context = {
        'obj': obj,
    }
    html = render_to_string(template_name, context)
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

index.html

```
<h1>{{ obj }}</h1>
```

myapp.js

```
$('#myid').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: GET_DATA,
        data: dataString,
        success: function(res) {
            $('#addl_container').html(res);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The problem here is if this is an api url and i want to access it from another site i want only json response vs html.

Comment: That's fine, you can still use `return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data))` on your data. I think as long as you know the purpose, you can go either way & adjust accordingly. Great question by the way

Answer (score 0):

very rough draft, from what I actually use, which is **Handlebar**:

in Django template. **head**:

```
<!--Handlebar templates start-->
{% include "app/mydiv.handlebars.html" %}
<!--Handlebar templates end-->
```

**app/mydiv.handlebars.html**

```
{% verbatim %}
<script id="template-myapp-my-div" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<div>All Details Here, 1.{{res.id}} res.id, 2. {{res.name}}</div>
</script>
{% endverbatim %}
```

Something like this in JS:

```
_success = function(json_data_from_response) { 
var templateSource = $("#template-myapp-mydiv").html();
if (!templateSource) {
    $("#errors").html("template-myapp-mydiv:error:no template found");
    return;
}
// you could compile ahead of time elsewhere or cache the compile.
var template = Handlebars.compile(templateSource);

// now merge your incoming data.
var myhtml = template(json_data_from_response);
$("#addl_container").html(myhtml);
);
```

I didn't go into the Handlebars templating details, but they are 80% similar to Django templates, minus the tag and filters, so you should it easy enough.

An additional benefit of using Handlebars is it that it can provide sprintf/python-type string substitutions in the client.  Kind of heavyweight for that use, but if you have it anyway...

```
//compute an actual url on the fly from a template (i.e. depending on
//what the user clicked on, I compute what to fetch)

var _url = _settings.url_details_base;
var t_url = Handlebars.compile(_url);
var url = t_url({"CREF": CREF,"rdbname" : rdbname});

//do something with url, like an Ajax call.
```